# How to access a dynamically generated html class name from a JS controller?

Tags: javascript, controller, html, aura, dynamic

I was trying to concat a class name with index from the iteration component. If it's correct, how can I access this value from the JS controller?

Component:

```
<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>

    <ul aura:id="list" class="slds-grid slds-grid_pull-padded slds-wrap"
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.funds}" var="fund" indexVar="index">
            <c:FundTile fund="{!fund}" index="{!index}"/>

           <lightning:button name="popover" label="Show Popover" onclick="{!c.handleShowPopover}"/>
            <div class="{!'mypopover' + index}" onmouseover="{!c.handleShowPopover}">Popover should display if you hover over here.</div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
handleShowPopover : function(component, event, helper) {

    var refname = document.getElementsByClassName("mypopover");

    component.find('overlayLib').showCustomPopover({
        body: "Popovers are positioned relative to a reference element",
        referenceSelector: refname,
        cssClass: "popoverclass"
    }).then(function (overlay) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            //close the popover after 3 seconds
            overlay.close();
        }, 3000);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the event parameter to get the element that called the method. `event.getSource()` will return you the component that fired the event. Using that you can get the index of the element that was clicked.

Comment: Thanks!

I've managed to get the value from child component which stored the index of the list.

class="{!'name'+v.index}"

var refname = component.get("v.index");